# How to make new domain on local pc?

Tags: dns, localhost

Can someone point me where I can find application/service used for creating NEW domain names?

If I want to create domain for example: **somethingnew.com** and I don't want to purchase it somewhere on net and redirect it on my pc, I want program/service that will allow me to own same way of registering as those online service have, just on my pc locally...

Is this possible?

I would like to use it with WAMP ( Apache ) server, if that is possible...

If anyone have any direction what would be useful, what program/service, I will appreciate that...

I try with Simple DNS Plus application, but it's not working okay...

Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Can someone explain me why he put -1? I asked a question, if I know the answer I wouldn't ask, and if you think it's stupid to ask, then just ANSWER, and not put -1... It's stupid...

Comment: It's off topic.  This is not by any stretch a programming question.

Comment: I gave u up vote. I think was good question

Comment: Read FAQ, and you will see "software tools commonly used by programmers"... It's question related to this site... Shahzeb thanks for support...

Comment: What "software tools" are we talking about here?  I repeat: *This has nothing to do with programming.*

Comment: Disagree, local domains are essential for testing web applications.  All the programmers I know use local domains for this.

Comment: I needed it globally, accessible from whole world, but I found out that that is not simple, so I stopped... Thanks to @Lee, I learn a little bit more about domains locally, and it will help a lot with developing sites on local machine... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like with the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)?  Just add your local domain names to your local PC's hosts file.

Comment: yes, with everything... I need domains to redirect to my IP, and Apache will deliver files... I just need ability to register new domains on my local pc...

Answer (score 2):

Edit file C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Within place a line like this:

```
127.0.0.1 somethingnew.com www.somethingnew.com
```

This will cause your local system to resolve the above domain names to the local IP address.

This file is usually restricted access so you might need to be admin user.

> I would like to use it with WAMP ( Apache ) server, if that is possible...

The SimpleDNS Plus tool you mentioned looks like a full DNS nameserver, which would only work with registered domains (nameservers are assigned to your registered domain).

[WampDeveloper Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper), a WAMP application, has a LocalDNS tab that does the above, but is not a free tool.

[HostsMan](http://www.abelhadigital.com/hostsman) and [HostsFileEditor](http://hostsfileeditor.codeplex.com/), are some other options, though I've not used these two before.